# merge: faulty hit by similarity index - how to fix?

Tags: git

I have feature branch where I modified file **A**/CMakeLists.txt
Whereas on master branch, two operations were performed:

1. file **A**/CMakeLists.txt was modified and moved to **B**/CMakeLists.txt
2. new file **C**/CMakeLists.txt was created

Now, when I merge my branch to master git insists that **B**/CMakeLists.txt is a new file and **A**/CMakeLists.txt was moved to **C**/CMakeLists.txt. With this assumption it tries to merge my changes to file in **C** instead of **B**.
Is there any way to tell git during merge process that its guess was wrong and order it to re-try using different way?

Answer (score 0):

*Update for information from comments*

---

The obvious thing is to try to "fix" the behavior of the merge.  And that can certainly be done, and it's most likely what you ought to do.  (There is a small, potential down side [1], but it's probably the lesser evil.)

The only way I can think to "tweak" the automated rename-guessing behavior would be to change the similarity threshold; but that won't really help - because for git to be picking the "wrong" file means that the "wrong" file is "more similar", so increasing the threshold will eliminate the "right" file before it eliminates the "wrong" one.

You could disable rename detection entirely, but then your changes from the branch will go to the `A` directory, which also isn't what I think you want.

So there is likely no way to clue git in, so that its automatic behavior becomes correct.  But an option that seems more promising to me is to say, you know, this shouldn't happen that often, so a manual fix might be ok.

```
git merge --no-commit myFeatureBranch
```

The merge result will be placed in the work tree and index, but not committed, so you can adjust the result.

```
git checkout $(git merge-base HEAD MERGE_HEAD) -- A/CMakeLists.txt
mv A/CMakeLists.txt tmp-BASE.txt
git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- A/CMakeLists.txt
git checkout HEAD -- B/CMakeLists.txt
git checkout HEAD -- C/CMakeLists.txt
git merge-file B/CMakeLists.txt tmp-BASE.txt A/CMakeLists.txt
```

This may result in conflicts in B/CMakeLists.txt, in which case you resolve them as per a normal merge.  Then clean up and finish the merge:

```
rm A/CMakeLists.txt
rm tmp-BASE.txt
git add .
git commit
```

---

[1] The potential issue with fixing the merge: *if* the merge is completing without conflict (but just getting the wrong result), then after you fix the merge, you'll have a sort of "evil merge".  In this case it's not *very* evil; the merge result is a bit ambiguous, and the difference between the accepted merge result and the default merge result fall within that ambiguity.  Still, in theory it could cause problems with future rebase operations, if the range of commits to rewrite would run through the merge.

Even so, the other option is to rewrite history in such a way that you can merge the branch changes in before file C is created.  That may be much easier said than done, and if any of the affected history is already shared, then that creates "upstream rebase" problems.

So... that's there for completeness, and if it concerns you enough to want to avoid the merge fix, then the next step would be to look into how a history rewrite might work.

Comment: git calculates the similarity threshold against all delete/add pairs, and then uses the most similar.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - If that's the case, then no amount of tweaking the threshold will matter; which would then refer the matter to either a `no-commit` merge and manual fix, or a history edit

Comment: Right: if path P does not exist in one of <base,left,right> but does exist in the other of the two being compared, Git tries all such files (all add/delete pairs) for similarity and picks the "most similar" one if its similarity index exceeds the chosen threshold. You can raise the threshold, to 100% if you like, to avoid any such matching (100% match occurs only if the files are identical).

Comment: With two sources (and particularly as I know that torek is rarely wrong about this sort of thing), I've updated the answer accordingly.